# Creating new user role in Laravel 5.2

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, role

I am trying to create a new role `originating_point_user` in Laravel 5.2, besides user  and admin. For that I have created a directory called `OriginatingPointAuth` within which there are two files `AuthController.php` and `PasswordController.php`. Also modified the `kernal.php` as below :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
        'origination_point_user' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotOriginationpointUser::class,
    ];
```

And `auth.php` as

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
        'originating_point_users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\OriginatingPointUser::class,
        ]
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

but when I tried to visit a route using `originating_point_user` middleware, it shows

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:  Class
>   originating_point_user does not exist

Route :

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'originating-point-user'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'loading-details'], function() {
        Route::get('/add', [
            'as' => 'opu.loading_details.create',
            'middleware' => ['originating_point_user'],
            'uses' => 'OrdersController@add_loading_details'
        ]);
    });
});
```

Also , it does not redirect to mentioned page defined in `AuthController.php`

Comment: do you have the model for the `OriginatingPointUser` ?

Comment: Yes I have a model `OriginatingPointUser.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your kernel file you have registered your middleware as `origination_point_user` instead of  `originating_point_user` . And when when calling the middleware you are calling with `originating_point_user`.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
 //change here originating_point_user
           'originating_point_user' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotOriginationpointUser::class,
    ];
```